# Como implementar um reduce para transformar um array em um objeto

Tags: javascript

// 30) Escreva um algoritmo que percorre um vetor de inteiros e defina o maior e menor valor dentro do vetor.

```
const maiorEMenorValor = (vetor) => {
  return vetor.reduce((prev, current) => {
    if(prev.maiorValor < current) {
      return prev.maiorValor = current
    }else if(prev.menorValor > current) {
      return prev.menorValor = current
    }
  },{menorValor: 0, maiorValor: 0})
}
const vetor2 = [20, 16, 3, 12, 5, 34, 6, 13, 71, 178, 24332, 1, 88]
console.log(maiorEMenorValor(vetor2))
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

No fim das contas basta retornar o objeto a cada iteração do reduce no array...

```
const maiorEMenorValor = (vetor) => {
  return vetor.reduce((acc, el) => {
    let novoMaiorValor
    let novoMenorValor
    if(acc.maiorValor < el) {
      
      novoMaiorValor = el
      novoMenorValor = acc.menorValor
      
    }else if(acc.menorValor > el) {
      
      novoMaiorValor = acc.maiorValor
      novoMenorValor = el
      
    }
    return { 
      maiorValor: novoMaiorValor ? novoMaiorValor : acc.maiorValor,
      menorValor: novoMenorValor ? novoMenorValor : acc.menorValor
    }
  },{ maiorValor: 0, menorValor: vetor[0]})
}
const vetor2 = [20, 16, 3, 12, 5, 34, 6, 13, 71, 178, 242, 1, 88]

console.log(maiorEMenorValor(vetor2))
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).